Seeking quote about Georges Lemaître and visualization of 4 dimensions
I have been trying for some time to track down a quote about Georges Lemaître, which I recall reading a few years ago. The author was another cosmologist, who met Lemaître at a conference. Lemaître asked him about his visualization of 4 dimensional space. When the author replied that he couldn't visualize it, Lemaître expressed his pity, and asked whether it was too late for the author to change his field.
Does anyone else remember this story? If so, I'd appreciate a pointer. Google hasn't been helpful.

Was the other author Stephen Hawking? Because in A Brief History of Time he wrote: "It is impossible to imagine a four-dimensional space. I personally find it hard enough to visualize three-dimensional space!"

@Mauricio Thanks, but I don't think so. The date (SH was born 1942, GM died 1966) don't make it impossible, but it seems unlikely.
